Problem with Basic Auth authentication in GLPI API (error "ERROR_APP_TOKEN_PARAMETERS_MISSING")
I’m working with GLPI version 9.5.13, and I’m trying to use the API to authenticate via Basic Auth (login and password) on the initSession endpoint.
I’ve followed the documentation and tried using a GET request with the Authorization: Basic {login:password} header to obtain a session token. However, despite this, I keep getting the following error:

[   "ERROR_APP_TOKEN_PARAMETERS_MISSING",   "The parameter app_token is missing; See the documentation in your browser at https://helpdesk.******.com/apirest.php/#ERROR_APP_TOKEN_PARAMETERS_MISSING" ]

Here’s what I’ve tried:

I would like to understand why the API keeps asking for an app_token even though I'm only using the login/password pair. Is there a specific configuration in GLPI that I need to change to disable the requirement for the app_token?

The answer is quite late but what is the problem about using the app token here?
Also, I would suggest to use a user token instead of credentials with login & password.
Anyway, you have a point, the official API docs say the app_token is optional but in most cases it is actually required.
I have developed a whole bidirectional interface between GLPI and another ticketing system, it worked perfectly fine with just including the app_token in session creation.
